# Evaluating JSON dynamic name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to display a database value and build a bootstrap grid, building the bootstrap grid was easy however displaying the data isn't as easily built.

Normally I would call the items I wanted in the loop like this `x[i].DIAG;`. However I am building a dynamically variable name "s": `var s = i*cNum+j` so that I can call the item dynamically `x[s].DIAG`. When I display the value with `console.log(s)`, I see the values I want. However, when I try output the data it breaks. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

**JSON example:**

```
0: Object
   DIAG:"Anaplastic"
   DIAGID:13
```

**Code:**

```
function loadDiag(){
    $.ajax({type: "GET"
          , dataType: "json"
          , url: "CFCs/lookUps.cfc"
          , data: {method: "Diag_rlu"}
          , success: function(data){
                 var x = data.items;
                 console.log(x)
                 var rNum = x.length / 6 //number of rows
                 var cNum = 6 // number of colums
                 var str = '';
                 for (var i = 0; i < rNum; i++) {
                     str += '<div class="row" id="'+i+'">';
                     for (var j = 0; j < cNum; j++) {
                         var s = i*cNum+j
                         if(s <= x.length){
                            str += '<div class="col-xs-2">'+x[s].DIAG+'</div>';
                         } else{
                            str += '<div class="col-xs-2"></div>';
                         }
                    }

                    str += '</div>';
                 }
                 $('.diagnosis').html(str);
              }
          });
       }
```

Comment: Phrases like "it breaks" are very ambiguous. What is the actual result of the code (error, etcetera) and how is it different than what you expected? Also, why the CF tags? This seems to be a javascript question.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my post; also you are correct it is a javascript question it has been corrected thanks again Leigh.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have an answer on this one. However, I suspect if you can elaborate on the error you are getting (and what exactly what `data.items` contains because it sounds different than the JSON sample) I am betting someone else will.

Comment: I can actually: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DIAG' of undefined. I do believe that the javascript is not evaluating the variable "s". Strangely when I console.log(x[s].DIAG) it shows the data I want to display just not in the HTML.

Comment: So for one thing, shouldn't it be `if(s < x.length){`-- arrays are 0-based, so your index should never be equals to the length. Maybe it's just that one call that issues the error?

Comment: That was it! works perfect! thank you MacPrawn